# Can I use my UK C-type business visa for a tourism trip?

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, tourist-visas

My visa was issued in October 2015, valid for 2 years. and it is C type Business. Since I received my visa a little later than the proposed meeting dates, I did not travel. Now I intend to travel as a tourist for 9 days. Can I still use that visa?